# How to invoke the Cucumber runner class from a different main method

Tags: java, cucumber, command-line-interface, program-entry-point, cucumber-jvm

I'm new to using Command Line Interface. So I just have a question on how to invoke the runner class of the cucumber using CLI technique.

I have a Java program which contains a main method. When testers pass the argument which is test case, it will fetch the feature file. The java program invoke a custom made API which will fetch the correct feature file.

Next I'll have to invoke the Cucumber runner class to execute the test case. I need to pass this particular feature file as the argument. Two questions, Can we invoke the runner class from a different main method. I did some research and I was not able to find a concrete answer. 
Two questions,

1. cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(arguments); So how do i specify the jar location of my runner class.

   `FeatureFileCreation.main("xxxxx"); - API that fetches the right feature file
   String[] arguments = {"-", ""}; 
   cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(arguments);

   - How do I specify where my jar is located? How can I pass my feature file?`
2. Should I create a main method in the runner class, something like this? For the sake of using CLI,Since I need to create a runnable jar. I should have a main method in my runner class.

`

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(features="C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/CRAutomation/CR Regression1/src/My.feature",glue={"bell.canada.step.definition"})

public class AutomationRunnerAction { 

    public void main(){
    }
}`
```

Please note that, Getting the right feature file is 1 java API. I will invoking that API from one main method of one java program. The runner class with step definition and methods are a diff java program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the accept answer is not correct. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/cli/Main.java) of `Main.main()` you'll notice that it contains: `System.exit(exitstatus)` which terminates the system.

The proper way to run the commandline programatically would be to use `Main.run()` like this:

```
String [] argv = new String[]{ "-g","","./src/main/java/featureDetails/Testing.feature"};
ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
byte exitstatus = Main.run(argv, contextClassLoader);
```

Comment: it working for single execution but how to ran it parallel execution with cucumber4 .. I am using below method : String [] argv =    String [] argv =  new String[] { 
    "--threads", "4", "-g", "parallel",
    "-p", "timeline:reports/timeline", 
    "./src/test/resources/features/"
    };
  

  ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  byte exitstatus = Main.run(argv, contextClassLoader);

Answer (score 2):

Try this if this works. You do not need any `Runner class`. Just call the static main method of `Main class` that corresponds to running cucumber from cli.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

           //Your code to get feature file full path        

            Main.main(new String[]{"-g", "classpath to step definition file", "Full path to feature file"});

          // My stepdefinition is inside java package at cucumber.sample.test
          // My feature file is inside src/test/resources/features/samplethree.feature

        }
```

For additional parameters like tags or plugin use `"-t","@Tags"`. **Important** the feature file path has to be the last option.

I am running this for Eclipse with Maven setting up classpath and jar dependencies.

Comment: I just provided my classpath - which is the src file of my java program and the full feature file path. But I am getting the error as "You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:". But I have the corresponding methods in the step definition file. Help would be much appreciated. Parallelly I'll check what is the issue in other forums. Just providing an update!

Comment: `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

public class AutomationRunnerAction {
 public static void main(){ 
 }
}`

Comment: You do not need any Runner if you are using Main. You have to provide the classpath in the glue option.

Comment: Are you suggesting to have a empty main method.                                     
`  public class AutomationRunnerAction {

 public static void main(){
 
 }
}  ` I have a package named step definition where all my annotation methods are there. I need a create a class with empty main method in the same package?

Comment: Create a simple Java class... Copy the main method that is in the answer... Add the api to get the feature file... Set up the glue code and full feature file location.. Run it as a java application... Hopefully it works

Comment: @Grasshopper, Could you please give more info on the --glue option from you code example. -->"classpath to step definition file", Myproj location: C:\myproj\Cuketest3, featurefile: C:\myproj\Cuketest3\cuketest2.feature StepDefJavaFile: C:\myproj\Cuketest3\Script4.java, also the .class is present in the same location as .java file

Comment: @user578219 - Seems that the stepdefs are not inside any package and you are running from command prompt. If you create the above runner in a class named Runner.java inside the Cuketest3 folder. Switch to this Cuketest3 folder and add '.' to the existing classpath. I do not think you need to add a glue option if the stepdefs are also in the same folder. Compile and run from the Cuketest3 folder. If the stepdefs are inside a 'stepdefs' package then add 'stepdefs' as the gle option.

Comment: Hi, I would like to provide multiple glue options like {"-g", "glue, glue1", "feature file"});. It doesn't work but adding -g option works, {"-g", "glue", "-g", "glue1", "feature file"}); Is it how its designed because this works in the CucumberOptions Annotations

Comment: Thanks. You mean in CLI we need to specify 2 glue options and with annotations we can do with single glue option.? Also, how to specify ANDing and ORing of --tags option with Main.main() ?

Comment: @user578219 This is the class which does the parsing logic - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/RuntimeOptions.java. Regarding tags, if you want to OR then use '-t tag1,tag2'. So for 'OR' you can get away with one tag option. For 'AND' you will need to use it twice or however many times  '-t tag1 -t tag2'. If you need a combination of OR and AND then '-t tagor1,tagor2 -t tagand3'. This will run scenarios with tagand3 and having both or one of tagor1 and tagor2.  Add the 'at the rate' symbol in front of tag, SO allows a single 'at the rate'

Comment: @user578219 Regarding glue the parsing logic assumes that each option is an independent package path. So I guess will throw an error if it finds comma etc when trying to get to the step definitions.

Comment: great. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Grasshopper - How to use it with parallel execution .. I have tried below but it just ask me to implement the method while they are already prersent and working with maven build. below is the implementation I have tried:

String [] argv = String [] argv = new String[] { "--threads", "4", "-g", "parallel", "-p", "timeline:reports/timeline", "./src/test/resources/features/" }; ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); byte exitstatus = Main.run(argv, contextClassLoader);

Comment: @ShubhamJain guessing u r talking of step definition methods, u need to check the classpath or the glue location setting in the command.

Comment: how do you set the classpath?