# Is there a specific way to call a particular scenario from the java code, not using TestRunner and Tags?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, karate

I need to call a particular scenario from my Java code. It is not required in simple cucumber-selenium framework, but I need this so I can incorporate cucumber with karate. and I want to keep a single feature file with karate scenarios and then call them according to my need from cucumber step-definition.

Comment: If you are talking of pure cucumber (do not know anything about karate) you can call the Main class of cucumber(package cucumber.api.cli) directly. Refer to this answer I had provided earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518103/how-to-invoke-the-cucumber-runner-class-from-a-different-main-method/43519626#43519626. I have not tried executing a specific scenario but if you pass the line number along with the feature file name it should work - features/test.feature:7.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer @Grasshopper, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please refer to the documentation on calling Karate via the [Java API](https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api)

But you need to split scenarios into separate feature files. You can't "select" one to call via the Java API. If you really need such an option, please raise a feature request, but I don't consider it to be a priority.

Comment: Well at times, it is not required to run all scenarios present in a feature file and I want to circumvent where I have to create different feature file for different scenarios.

Comment: If you really want Scenarios to be "re-usable" there is nothing wrong with moving it into a separate file. Don't be lazy :P

Comment: This would be the easiest solution but as your automation scales up, having lots of feature files could be troublesome at the least. So need an alterantive.

Comment: I disagree. But sure, you are entitled to your opinion, raise a feature request or better still, submit a pull request. That's what open source is all about. Right ?

Comment: Yup, but I'm not familiar with github that much. Let's see.

Comment: Why don't you reach the point where your automation "scales up" to be "troublesome" and then we'll talk :P

Comment: hahahaa.. It pays to be proactive, wouldn't you agree? It's only been 4 days since I started with karate and already felt the need. Anyways it will be a cool feature to have in karate.